# Alamofire/RxSwift how to refresh token and retry requests automatically on status code 401

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire, rx-swift

I need help with automatically retrying requests after i get first 401 status code on any request. I'm using RxSwift and Alamofire so the call looks like this:

```
public func getSomeEndpointInfo() -> Observable<PKKInfo> {
    return Observable.create({ observer in
        let request = AF.request(Router.info)
        request
            .responseDecodable(of: Info.self) { response in
                print("response: \(response)")
                if response.response?.statusCode == 401 {
                    observer.onError(NetworkError.unauthorized)
                }
                guard let decodedItems = response.value else {
                    observer.onError(NetworkError.invalidJSON)
                    return
                }
                observer.onNext(decodedItems)
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
        return Disposables.create()
    })
}
```

Now in some service I have the following code:

```
service.getSomeEndpointInfo()
.observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
.subscribe { [unowned self] info in
    self._state.accept(.loaded)
} onError: { [unowned self] error in
    print("---> Error")
    self.sessionManager
        .renewToken()
        .observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe { token in
            print("---> recieved new token")
            self.service.getSomeEndpointInfo()
        } onError: { error in
            print("---> error generating token")
        }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

With this code works but I have to call renew token on every request and its embedded into error subscription which doesn't feel well. If you have some other suggestion that on 401 I somehow retry requests and trigger renew token before that i would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on how to do this. [RxSwift and Handling Invalid Tokens](https://danielt1263.medium.com/retrying-a-network-request-despite-having-an-invalid-token-b8b89340d29).

The article comes complete with code and tests proving functionality. The key is the class at the bottom of this answer.

You use it like this:

```
typealias Response = (URLRequest) -> Observable<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)>

func getData<T>(response: @escaping Response, tokenAcquisitionService: TokenAcquisitionService<T>, request: @escaping (T) throws -> URLRequest) -> Observable<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)> {
    return Observable
        .deferred { tokenAcquisitionService.token.take(1) }
        .map { try request($0) }
        .flatMap { response($0) }
        .map { response in
            guard response.response.statusCode != 401 else { throw TokenAcquisitionError.unauthorized }
            return response
        }
        .retryWhen { $0.renewToken(with: tokenAcquisitionService) }
}
```

You can use currying to make a function that shares the service...

```
func makeRequest(builder: @escaping (MyTokenType) -> URLRequest) -> Observable<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)> {
    getData(
        response: { URLSession.shared.rx.response(request: $0) /* or however Moya makes network requests */ },
        tokenAcquisitionService: TokenAcquisitionService<MyTokenType>(
            initialToken: getSavedToken(),
            getToken: makeRenewTokenRequest(oldToken:),
            extractToken: extractTokenFromData(_:)),
        request: builder)
}
```

Use the above function anywhere in your code that needs token renewal.

Here is the TokenAquisitionService used above. Have all your requests use the same service object.

```
public final class TokenAcquisitionService<T> {

    /// responds with the current token immediatly and emits a new token whenver a new one is aquired. You can, for example, subscribe to it in order to save the token as it's updated.
    public var token: Observable<T> { get }

    public typealias GetToken = (T) -> Observable<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)>

    /// Creates a `TokenAcquisitionService` object that will store the most recent authorization token acquired and will acquire new ones as needed.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - initialToken: The token the service should start with. Provide a token from storage or an empty string (object represting a missing token) if one has not been aquired yet.
    ///   - getToken: A function responsable for aquiring new tokens when needed.
    ///   - extractToken: A function that can extract a token from the data returned by `getToken`.
    public init(initialToken: T, getToken: @escaping GetToken, extractToken: @escaping (Data) throws -> T)

    /// Allows the token to be set imperativly if necessary.
    /// - Parameter token: The new token the service should use. It will immediatly be emitted to any subscribers to the service.
    public func setToken(_ token: T)
}

extension ObservableConvertibleType where Element == Error {
    /// Monitors self for `.unauthorized` error events and passes all other errors on. When an `.unauthorized` error is seen, the `service` will get a new token and emit a signal that it's safe to retry the request.
    ///
    /// - Parameter service: A `TokenAcquisitionService` object that is being used to store the auth token for the request.
    /// - Returns: A trigger that will emit when it's safe to retry the request.
    public func renewToken<T>(with service: TokenAcquisitionService<T>) -> Observable<Void>
}
```